# Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in header.php

Tags: php, arrays, opencart, opencart2.x

After install my extension i see this error in my admin page:

> Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/store/admin/controller/common/header.php on line 58
>   Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/store/admin/controller/common/header.php on line 59
>   Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/store/admin/controller/common/header.php on line 62
>   Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/store/admin/controller/common/header.php on line 63

header.php

```
    // Processing Orders
    $data['order_status_total'] = $this->model_sale_order->getTotalOrders(array('filter_order_status' => implode(',', $this->config->get('config_processing_status'))));
    $data['order_status'] = $this->url->link('sale/order', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . '&filter_order_status=' . implode(',', $this->config->get('config_processing_status')), 'SSL');

    // Complete Orders
    $data['complete_status_total'] = $this->model_sale_order->getTotalOrders(array('filter_order_status' => implode(',', $this->config->get('config_complete_status'))));
    $data['complete_status'] = $this->url->link('sale/order', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . '&filter_order_status=' . implode(',', $this->config->get('config_complete_status')), 'SSL');
```

in database(complete_status_total):

```
a:1:{i:0;s:1:"7";}
```

How do can i fix this error?!

Comment: That's a serialized data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `unserialize` that.

For example:

```
$data = 'a:1:{i:0;s:1:"7";}'
$unserialized_data = unserialize($data); //Unserialized string to array
print_r($unserialized_data);

$imploded_data = implode(',', unserialized_data); //Implode your array
echo $imploded_data;
```